# Cast To Interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, casting

I am not getting any errors in my code, but my filter object is always null. When I run the debugger the filter object looks just like the sort object, a list with stuff in it. Although as you can see it is actually a interface.. What do I need to change in this code to access the information in the filter? I guess my main problem is I don't quite fully grasp how to work with interfaces.

```
public IList<Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor> Filters { get; set; }
public IList<Kendo.Mvc.SortDescriptor> Sorts { get; set; }
```

```
List<SortDescriptor> sort = request.Sorts as List<SortDescriptor>;
if(sort.Count == 1)
{
    pRequest.SortMember = sort[0].Member;
    pRequest.SortDirection = (int)sort[0].SortDirection;

}

List<FilterDescriptor> filter = request.Filters as List<FilterDescriptor>;
if (filter != null)
{
    pRequest.Startdate = (DateTime)filter[0].ConvertedValue;
}
else
{
    var endDate = new TimeSpan(4000, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    pRequest.Startdate = DateTime.UtcNow - endDate;
}
```

Comment: Problem is, `List<T>` is not covariant. And even if it was, it would make cast from `List<Class>` to `List<IInterface>` possible, not the opposite. Btw. I don't think you need these casts at all.

Comment: Hmm you're right, I dont need those casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys I talked to a friend of mine and he suggested I do this... So I guess I should not have been trying to cast the Lists and Interfaces.

```cs
    if(request.Sorts.Count == 1)
    {
        pRequest.SortMember = request.Sorts[0].Member;
        pRequest.SortDirection = (int)request.Sorts[0].SortDirection;
    }

    if (request.Filters.Count >= 1)
    {
        foreach(var item in request.Filters)
        {
            if(item is Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor)
            {
                 var descriptor = (Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor)item;
                 pRequest.Startdate = (DateTime)descriptor.ConvertedValue;
            }
        }                
    }
    else
    {
         var endDate = new TimeSpan(4000, 0, 0, 0, 0);
         pRequest.Startdate = DateTime.UtcNow - endDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The list is null because you are trying to cast `List<IFilterDescriptor>` into `List<FilterDescriptor>`, but just because `FilterDescriptor` inherits from `IFilterDescriptor` doesn't mean that `List<FilterDescriptor>` inherits from `List<IFilterDescriptor>` (unless the list is covariant `List<in T>` which it isn't).

You should do it like this:

```
IList<IFilterDescriptor> filter = request.Filters;
```

if the interface is fine with that, otherwise you can case the list like that:

```
List<FilterDescriptor> filter = request.Filters.OfType<FilterDescriptor>.ToList();
```

Comment: assigning `request.Filters` to `List<IFilterDescriptor>` requires explicit cast.

Comment: It doesn't because notice i have also changed to type from `FilterDescriptor` to `IFilterDescriptor` in the generic type too.
If you mean casting from `IList` to `List` than you just need to add `.ToList()` in the end.

Comment: Yes, I mean casting from `IList` to `List`.

Comment: Your first suggestion does not create error, but unfortunately the filter object does not contain any attributes. Your second suggestion does not work because request.Filters does not know what .OfType is.

Comment: The second one was a typo, i fixed it... Please reexplain about the first one.