# C# Grab value from Expression

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my program I am trying to pull **Value** below into a variable:

[image]

Via:

```
var member = (object)request.Filters[0];
string value = member.Value;
```

The problem is my program won't compile even though the value I am trying to get clearly exists. I.e:

[image]

Request/Filter is defined below:

```
//request object:
....
public IList<IFilterDescriptor> Filters { get; set; }
...

//IFilterDescriptor object:

public interface IFilterDescriptor
{
    Expression CreateFilterExpression(Expression instance);
}
```

How can I grab the value from the object?

Comment: Why are you casting to an object?

Comment: maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183268/578411

Comment: Why are you casting to `object` instead of `IFilterDescriptor`?

Comment: @rene it worked! Thank you! We can close the question or I can upvote and accept your answer